# How to save all the records into multiple CSV files based on distinct values in the column from the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to create multiple CSV files based on distinct column value in 'User'. I tried using below code but it seems incomplete.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob','Jane','Bob','Jane','Alice','Bob','Alice'],'income':[400,500, 420, 600,300,700,1000],'expenses':[400,2500,420,600,2000,700,1000]})
for i df['user'].unique():
  df.to_csv(outfile,index=True)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: _I tried using below code but it seems incomplete._ It **seems** incomplete? Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `groupby` & `sum` first.

```
>>> df.groupby(['user']).sum()                                                                                                                   

       income  expenses
user                   
Alice    1300      3000
Bob      1520      1520
Jane     1100      3100

# outputs the dataframe on top
>>> df.groupby(['user']).sum().to_csv(outfile, index=True)
```

for each user to its own csv file

```
# outputs each user with each rows to username.csv
>>>  [x[1].to_csv(f'{x[0]}.csv', index=True) for x in df.groupby('user', axis='index')]                                                          
[None, None, None]

>>> import csv

>>> with open('Alice.csv') as a: 
        alice = csv.reader(a) 
        for row in alice: 
            print(row) 

['', 'user', 'income', 'expenses']
['4', 'Alice', '300', '2000']
['6', 'Alice', '1000', '1000']
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I dont want sum. But I need all the separate records of Bob in one CSV file, Jane in second CSV file, Alice in third CSV file...and so on...

Comment: ah yes sorry, it's late here. So you want not just sum for each person?

Comment: yeah. i just need to create separate csv's based on 'user'.